# Make an registry file which contains multiple cascade context (sub) menu

Tags: windows, menu, cascade

Up front, i am not a good programmer, just a novice / beginner:

The following script has 2 levels of context menu (see screenshot)
What i am trying to do is 1 level more from within (like in the screenshot) remote control sub menu. So another sub menu IN the remote control sub menu

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\RemoteControl]
"Icon"="D:\\Mijn Data\\Portables\\VNC Viewer\\vncviewer.exe"
"MUIVerb"="Remote Control"
"Position"="Top"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\RemoteControl\Shell\01menu]
"MUIVerb"="TightVNC Viewer"
"Icon"="D:\\Mijn Data\\Portables\\TightVNCViewer\\TightVNCViewerPortable.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\RemoteControl\Shell\01menu\command]
@="D:\\Mijn Data\\Portables\\TightVNCViewer\\TightVNCViewerPortable.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\RemoteControl\Shell\02menu]
"MUIVerb"="VCN Viewer"
"Icon"="D:\\Mijn Data\\Portables\\VNC Viewer\\vncviewer.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\RemoteControl\Shell\02menu\command]
@="D:\\Mijn Data\\Portables\\VNC Viewer\\vncviewer.exe"
```

I've added this:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\RemoteControl\Shell\01menu]
"MUIVerb"="TightVNC Viewer"
"Icon"="D:\\Mijn Data\\Portables\\TightVNCViewer\\TightVNCViewerPortable.exe"
"SubCommands"=""
```

and it DID added a submenu, but without content, i've tried many ways, but the new content is not showing. (this example is not complete)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't uploaded the screenshot you mentioned and you should finish the example (as you wrote is incomplete).

I tried adding a 2nd level submenu using the same structure as with the 1st level submenu and it worked fine for me.

[image]